# Is it sensible to version topic strings?

Tags: mqtt

There seem to be some best practices concerning MQTT topics. Some are laid out on the hivemq website (amongst other things):

> Don’t use a leading forward slash
>   Don’t use spaces in a topic
>   Keep the topic short and concise

An example topic was

> myhome/livingroom/temperature

My question: **Could it be a good idea to include a version level in the topic string?** For example:

```
v1/myhome/livingroom/sensor/1/temperature
v2/myhome/livingroom/sensor/2/temperature
```

I am also thinking a little bit of versions in rest apis here.
In version 1 i send the temperature as a simple string. But later i could have decided that i want to use a JSON format for the message payload for newer sensors.

The receiving clients could check the version and handle the payload accordingly.

Comment: This question is going to be heavy on opinion as there is no right/wrong answer so not really suited for Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: The MQTT.org mailing list (http://mqtt.org/get-involved) may be a better venue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to support multiple versions at once, don't do it. If you absolutely have to, I'd suggest you do it at the sensor level, not root. This gives you some flexibility on replacing some sensors, not others e.g.:

```
myhome/livingroom/sensor/1/v1/temperature
```

or

```
myhome/livingroom/sensor/1/temperature/v1
```